# How do I retrieve Google SDK passphrase

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

[Following this post](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/transfer-files?hl=en), I'm trying to transfer code from my local machine to the compute engine but I forgot my passphrase.

Can someone tell me how to retrieve it.
I've searched around for solutions but found nothing.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Remove your old keys and try again, that is

```
rm ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine*
```

and then

```
gcloud compute ssh my_vm_name --zone zone_vm_is_in
```

Answer (score 3):

this below works as stated by @cherba

```
rm ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine*
```

after using this command you can then reset the password to the ssh passphrase or you can simply hit enter to leave no password. i am supplying this answer because if you use the command and then attempt to ssh into an instance it takes a few seconds for the keys to propagate. i wanted to add this as a comment but didn't have enough reputation points on stack overflow.

[image: ssh config]