# How to enter google cloud credentials once and never be asked about it again?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

On a Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.6 machine, I'm trying to use GNU parallel to issue gcloud commands simultaneously with different zones such as:

```
gcloud compute --project my-project ssh --zone us-west1-c server-1234 --command 'sudo ls'
```

But the problem is (when not running GNU parallel) you always get this passphrase prompt:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/admin/.ssh/google_compute_engine':
```

This means GNU parallel just hangs.  Is there a way to get to either bypass the passphrase prompt or set things up so that the user only has to enter it once on their computer?

Comment: By default, Google SSH keypairs do not have a passphrase. If yours do, then you will need to recreate them without a passphrase.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, just forgot to use ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub after restarting

Answer (score 0):

As @John mentioned in the comment to the question combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724728/1526703) answer:

1. You can recreate your keys without a passphrase.
2. Backup your old keys (if needed):

   ```
   mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine google_compute_engine_old
   mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub google_compute_engine_old.pub
   ```
3. Connect to ssh `gcloud compute ssh --project=PROJECT_ID --zone=ZONE VM_NAME` using your usual [command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#gcetools) and options.

You will see something like this:

```
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again:
```

**Leave the passphrase empty** and you won't be asked for it next time you ssh in