# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1]

Tags: gcloud

I'm just trying to move a simple text file from the local host to the remote host. I'm using Google's Cloud computing and more specifically,  I'm using the gcloud command line tool.  Here are the instructions and errors I received:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:downloads kylefoley$ gcloud compute scp lst_calc.txt instance-1:/home/kylefoley76/hey.txt
No zone specified. Using zone [us-central1-a] for instance: [instance-1].
Updating project ssh metadata...⠧Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/atomic-drake-250022].
Updating project ssh metadata...done.                                             
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.1494876250178113937' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine': 
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine': 
scp: /home/kylefoley76/hey.txt: Permission denied
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

I then tried putting `root@` in front of the remote path and got the following error:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:downloads kylefoley$ gcloud compute scp lst_calc.txt root@instance-1:/home/kylefoley76/hey.txt
No zone specified. Using zone [us-central1-a] for instance: [instance-1].
Updating project ssh metadata...⠛Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/atomic-drake-250022].
Updating project ssh metadata...done.                                             
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine': 
root@35.193.247.37: Permission denied (publickey).
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine': 
root@35.193.247.37: Permission denied (publickey).
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine': 
root@35.193.247.37: Permission denied (publickey).
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine': 
root@35.193.247.37: Permission denied (publickey).
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine':
```

It was then clear that the program was caught in an infinite loop of some kind.

---

UPDATE

---

Also, I want to make it clear that my problem is not a linux problem but a gcloud problem.  A lot of people who have this problem recommend putting the files in the `/tmp` folder. On the remote Linux computer that I'm connected to it seems that I have all of the necessary permissions.  I've created folders and files on this remote machine and I've moved the files around with terminal, so I think that rules out the possibility that my problem lies with the permissions of the Linux computer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason of the message:

> **This message means that the network connection from the client to the server is working, and that SSH is running. However, key-based authenticatication failed.**

---

### Troubleshooting steps:

> - **Make sure that you have authenticated to gcloud as an IAM user with the [compute instance admin role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#instance_admin_role).**

run `gcloud auth login [IAM-USER]` then try `gcloud compute ssh` again.

> - **Verify that persistent SSH Keys metadata for gcloud is set for either the project or instance.**

`gcloud compute project-info describe --format flattened | grep 
   commonInstanceMetadata.items | grep ssh | grep -v expireOn`

> - **It's possible that you lost the private key, mismatched a keypair, etc. You can force gcloud to generate a new SSH keypair by doing the following:**

1. If present, by moving `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` and `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub`. For example:

   > `mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub.old`
   >
   > `mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.old`
2. Try `gcloud compute ssh [INSTANCE-NAME]` again. A new keypair will be created and the public key will be added to the SSH keys metadata.

> - **Verify that the [Linux Guest Environment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages) scripts are installed and
>     running. If the Linux Guest
>     Environment is not installed, re-install it.**

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I put in the command `gcloud compute scp -rp -i /Users/kylefoley/.ssh/google_compute_engine lst_calc.txt instance-1:/home/kylefoley76/hey.txt` and get back the error mesage that it did not recognize the argument `-rp` and `i`.  I then put in the command without those arguments and got the same error message.

Comment: I also tried that workaround of making a directory called `tmp` and putting the file in there but that did not work.  But in any case, such a workaround would be unacceptable if it worked, because I need to understand why I cannot perform this very simple task.

Comment: Hello @kylefoley76, I understand. Like I mentioned previously, your public key located in `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` is blocking the access to your files. Have you tried removing your old key `rm ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine*` and trying again? It may take a few seconds for the keys to propagate afterwards. Keep me posted. This was a solution for some people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719690/how-do-i-retrieve-google-sdk-passphrase/34724728)

Comment: I don't have a file `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` I do have a file called `~/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts`.  Do you recommend deleting that each time I destroy the instance of the virtual machine?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, but you do not need to destroy your VM instance. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719690/how-do-i-retrieve-google-sdk-passphrase/34724728) recommends to remove the file where your old [keys are located](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#locatesshkeys) and try to generate new ones when you run the `gcloud compute scp` [commands](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files?hl=en#transfergcloud). Please check out the links I shared with you for more info.

Comment: Thanks but in the links you posted the authors refer to a file called `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`.  I don't have such a file.  The closest thing I have with that name is `~/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts`.  I'm trying to figure out what I am getting a permission denied error when I run the command: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key kylefoley76@35.193.247.37`.  Are you saying that it is because of the old keys I have in the file `~/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts`?

Comment: Hi @kylefoley76, your issue is that when you try to copy your local file to a remote instance, you do not have the right permissions to perform this action. You can modify this by doing several things: passing the [argument](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp#--ssh-key-file) `--ssh-key-file=SSH_KEY_FILE]`. The path to the SSH key file. By default, this is `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`. You change it to where your public key is located. Also, you can [add project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide).

Comment: I'm going to have to read a book on this issue.  There's too many things I don't understand.  Thanks for your help.  I have no further questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200948/discussion-between-sllopis-and-kylefoley76).

Answer (score 4):

Create a tmp dir under your home in your instance with chmod 777 and send files to that.

```
gcloud compute scp ./app.tar.gz my-vm:~/tmp
```